# почему персонаж не поворачивается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Мне надо было сделать так, чтобы персонаж поворачивался при нажатии на стрелку вправо и влево.

Я написал код чтобы он поворачивался, но он не работает, почему?

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and rotate == "right":
    surf = pygame.transform.flip(surf, True, False)
    rotate = "left"
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and rotate == "left":  
    surf = pygame.transform.flip(surf, True, False)
    rotate = "right"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не предоставили минимально-воспроизводимый пример,
который демонстрирует проблему.
Поэтому не понятно почему он не работает.

Вот вам пример, в котором все работает:

```
import sys
import pygame


img = pygame.image.load('Ok.png')         
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('brown3')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((440, 380))
screen.fill((BG_COLOR))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                img = pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                img = pygame.transform.flip(img, False, True)   

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill((BG_COLOR))
    screen.blit(img,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]